# How to send emails to the registered users automatically by different dates

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I am doing a MERN Stack project. In my collection on MongoDB. a single document contains feilds like

- userName
- email
- lastDate

The **lastDate** property is different for different users.
I want to send an email to every user before 3 days of the
**lastDate** automatically. I have no idea how to do that. Please give me guidelines on how to do that. Thank you!

Comment: The lastDate will be what you search by and by age. It must be x-days old. When you perform a search you should be returned a list of users and their emails. You could loop through the results and when complete update database with new date for all users. The search would continue periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, In the past I was looking for a similar solution, I found this, you can use the module named [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) with nodemailer.

1. First install it.

```sh
node install node-cron --save
```

2. Import `node-cron` and schedule a task

```js
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
   console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

**Note**: You can read about several cron schedule patterns [here](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron). In the above example, we have scheduled a simple console log in every minute.

Here is the combined code where I am scheduling the e-mail to send every minute:

```js
  let cron = require('node-cron');
  let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  // e-mail message options
  let mailOptions = {
        from: '<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
        to: '<TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
        subject: 'Email from Node-App: A Test Message!',
        text: 'Some content to send'
   };

  // e-mail transport configuration
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: '<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
          pass: '<FROM_EMAIL_PASSWORD>'
        }
    });

 cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  // Send e-mail
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
  });
```